# Laravel: Undefined method "cannot"

Tags: php, laravel, neovim, language-server-protocol

What's weird about this is that the feature itself works perfectly fine, so I'm guessing it might be an issue with my intelephense but I have no idea how to fix or at least ignore the error message(in a safe way)? Also I am just simply following a tutorial, it's working fine for him and me but I'm just getting that error message.

This is what my function looks like:

```
public function delete(Post $post) {
    if (auth()->user()->cannot('delete', $post)) {
        return 'You cannot do that';
    }
    $post->delete()
}
```

I've already searched for this an saw someone suggesting to install a composer package called "laravel-ide-helper" but this didn't do anything.

Also, I'm using neovim with the intelephense LSP (free version) but when switch to another LSP called phpactor, I get a slightly different error message: Method "cannot" does not exist on class "Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable"

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you generate the actual files with laravel-ide-helper by doing `php artisan ide-helper:generate` and `php artisan ide-helper:models`?

Comment: Because this method does not exists. Use ! user()->can()

Comment: @Maksim it does exist: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/245e891e3ab17132a2aaeb6c1e32b80ec5426c68/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/Authorizable.php#L52-L55 and https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#via-the-user-model... Author, it is 100% related to intelephense. The "issue" with `laravel-ide-helper` is that some stuff is only understandable by PHPStorm -> `php artisan ide:meta`, which will tell PHPStorm how some stuff is related between them, for example, stuff that `auth()->user()` type is related to. I personally recommend 100% PHPStorm for Laravel + PHP, best choice

Comment: @matiaslauriti Hey thanks for the answer, yes I agree phpstorm is really good for Laravel especially as I use that for work but I can't afford it for personal use unfortunately, however I did find an alternative which does not give an error, I'll update the question for anyone else who stumbles upon this, thanks.

Comment: @WinBarua Yes, I am aware it is paid, I personally pay for it, but I understand not everyone can. Maybe you can use it freely by just using the EAP (beta releases), as that one is not paid, and it is [free to use](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2023/06/phpstorm-2023-2-eap-2/), but it could have some issues, as they are early builds, but usually, they do not have issues that will make you suffer from them. Only PHPSorm gave me the best balance between intelephense and other features by the Laravel community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Request class instead of the global auth() method to get the user seems to get rid of the error and still works as expected (I think the tutorial I was following has slightly outdated content)

Like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function delete(Request $request, Post $post) {
    if ($request->user()->cannot('delete', $post)) {
         return 'You cannot do that';
    }
    $post->delete()
}
```

Refer to the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#via-the-user-model